# Sorting API values in a table using php

Tags: php, json, api, echo

I'm trying to build something like https://coinranking.com/. I plan on doing this by sorting the results from the API at http://www.coincap.io/front using the `position24` value as sorting parameter.
So far, I managed to pull an ordered list with the prices, but I'd like to display the values from other objects (volume, mktcap, etc) as well in a table. Would I have to repeat this function for every object?

```
<php? 
function compare($a, $b) {
    return intval($a->position24) - intval($b->position24);
}

$json = file_get_contents('http://www.coincap.io/front');
$data = json_decode($json);
usort($data, 'compare');
foreach ($data as $item) {
    echo $item->price . "\n"<;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call it. For example like this:

```
echo $item->volume;
echo $item->mktcap;
```

in a table that would look like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Market Capitalization</th>
            <th>Volume</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($data as $row) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row->long; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row->price; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row->mktcap; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row->volume; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, really. Working like a charm.

Comment: One more thing: is it possible to make a value (eg: price) display only 2 decimals? I tried 'number_format((float) 2, '.', '')', but that didn't work.

Comment: It is possible. But PHP is not like Java, so you should use a different function to convert the variable. So to do that you should use `number_format(floatval($price), 2, '.','')`.

Answer (score 1):

`usort` expecting array as parameter your `$data` is object maybe you should use `json_decode($json,true);` and

```
function compare($a, $b) {
    return intval($a['position24']) - intval($b['position24']);
}
```